# why multi call of decodeURI not works?

Tags: javascript, node.js

here is an example:

```
// \u7ec6\u8f9b
console.log(decodeURI("%5Cu7ec6%5Cu8f9b"))
// 细辛
console.log(decodeURI("\u7ec6\u8f9b"))
// \u7ec6\u8f9b
console.log(decodeURI(decodeURI("%5Cu7ec6%5Cu8f9b")))
```

why not `decodeURI(decodeURI("%5Cu7ec6%5Cu8f9b"))` to be `细辛`?

[playground](https://repl.it/repls/DazzlingAverageMiddleware#index.js)

Comment: `console.log("\u7ec6\u8f9b")`… It's not `decodeURI` that's doing anything…

Comment: but why `console.log(decodeURI("%5Cu7ec6%5Cu8f9b"))` to be `\u7ec6\u8f9b` rather than `细辛` @deceze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
console.log(decodeURI("%5Cu7ec6%5Cu8f9b"))
```

This decodes the *percent encoded* string to its actual contents, which is "backslash u seven ...". The string contains those actual characters.

```js
console.log("\u7ec6\u8f9b")
```

This is a *JavaScript string literal* which contains *escape sequences* which are interpreted by the JavaScript parser. The JavaScript string literals `"\u7ec6\u8f9b"` and `"细辛"` are identical for all intents and purposes. Both of these strings contain the characters 细 and 辛, just written in different forms. There's no backslash in those strings.

```js
console.log(decodeURI("%5Cu7ec6%5Cu8f9b") == "\\u7ec6\\u8f9b");  // true
console.log(decodeURI("%5Cu7ec6%5Cu8f9b") == "\u7ec6\u8f9b");  // false
console.log("\u7ec6\u8f9b" == "细辛");  // true
```

`decodeURI` only decodes percent encoding, it does not decode Unicode escape sequences.

Comment: now i understand. the `"\"` of `"\u7ec6"` which is returned by decodeURI is a character `"\"` while `"\"` of string `"\u7ec6"` is an escape `"\"`.